# How to add custom artifacts extensions (RXTs) in WSO2 governance registry in form war file?

Tags: maven, wso2, governance-registry, wso2-governance-registry

I have no access to production environment, which is like no access to management console URL, or wso2 greg folder. If I need to add custom artifacts extension in wso2 greg server in form war file deployment, how would I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to management console or server folder location, there is no way that you can add a new RXT. However, there are some ways that we can inject files to the registry(in this case config registry, to add an rxt) using [registry API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Registry+REST+API), but it is highly not recommended by WSO2 and if you are doing that you have to do a proper testing round to check whether it's breaking any registry functionality.